# Standard for PointCloud messages is still PointCloud2?

Tags: ros, services, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

After some work with standalone PCL, I'm running the first tests of PCL under ROS.

I have a question: I understand that pcl::PointCloud is the preferred type for point clouds, and I was able to register a callback to kinect streams using just this type (without conversions to/from sensor_msgs::PointCloud2)

Now I was trying to implement a service that returns PointClouds. In order to define a service I need to specify a message type, and I only see sensor_msgs/PointCloud and PointCloud2.

My question is: this means that PointCloud2 is still the preferred standard for PointCloud messages, or am I missing a more specific message type that allows to handle pcl::PointCloud arguments?

Should I always work with sensor_msgs/PointCloud2 messages when playing with services, and perform conversions to pcl::PointCloud inside my code?

thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50272/standard-for-pointcloud-messages-is-still-pointcloud2?/) by [Kilin](https://answers.ros.org/users/3758/kilin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2012-12-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Short answer, yes. `sensor_msgs/PointCloud2` is the message type to transmit point clouds; if you want to do pcl processing with them you'll need to convert them to `pcl::PointCloud<T>` using `pcl::fromROSMsg` and `pcl::toROSMsg`.

For the long answer, see the [ROS/PCL overview](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pcl/Overview) and the [tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pcl/Tutorials). As indicated on the latter:

> The `sensor_msgs/PointCloud2` format was designed as a ROS message, and is the preferred choice for ROS applications.

> The `pcl/PointCloud<T>` format represents the internal PCL point cloud format. For modularity and efficiency reasons, the format is templated on the point type, and PCL provides a list of templated common types which are SSE aligned.

Hope it helps!

---

Originally posted by [Miguel S.](https://answers.ros.org/users/3547/miguel-s./) with karma: 1114 on 2012-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Neil Traft](https://answers.ros.org/users/17791/neil-traft/) on 2014-07-24**:
With Hydro and the introduction of `pcl::PCLPointCloud2` (as well as automatic serializers to convert b/w types), is this still true? Does `pcl::PCLPointCloud2` trump `pcl::PointCloud<T>`?